# Code stripped when using destroyShow() function inside $(window).resize() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, bxslider

When I put the `destroyShow()` function inside the `$(window).resize()` function it seems to strip out almost all of the code on my site when I resize the window. Very odd. Anyone know why this might be happening? Here's a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/r5D7u/1/

Comment: did you want to remove the slider or stop it ?

Comment: What I'd love to do is reload it using reloadShow() but there's some buggyness when I only use that and resize the window during a transition. The slides start moving really fast. So I figured I'd destroy it first, then try to reload it.. but destroy is giving me issues as well.

Comment: are you changing any content, that you want to use reloadShow()

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But I have a responsive layout and I want the bxSlider to reload when the browser window is resized. The reason is that bxSlider sets a fixed px width of the slider when the page loads. So I need to reload it so it can reload the widths.